# Check multiple checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, checkbox

I need to validate multiple checkbox in my form.
If "primi" and "secondi" are not ceck I will show an alert and if both are checked I will show another alert.

This is my form code:

```
<td><input class="quadrato" id="primi" name="primi" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
<td><input class="quadrato" id="primi" name="primi" type="checkbox" value="2" /></td>
<td><input class="quadrato" id="primi" name="primi" type="checkbox" value="3" /></td>

<td><input class="quadrato" id="secondi" name="secondi" type="checkbox" value="13" /></td>
<td><input class="quadrato" id="secondi" name="secondi" type="checkbox" value="14" /></td>
<td><input class="quadrato" id="secondi" name="secondi" type="checkbox" value="15" /></td>
<td><input class="quadrato" id="secondi" name="secondi" type="checkbox" value="16" /></td>
```

And this is the javascript funciton I use to ceck if "primi" is cecked:

```
var i, primi = document.getElementsByName('primi');
for (i = 0; i <= primi.length; i++){
    if (primi[i].checked){
        alert('yes');
        return true;
    } else{
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this works only if I select the first checkbox but not the other!
How can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are this checkboxes or radiobuttons? Is it possible to have more than one "primo" selected? or more than one "secondo"? btw as other have already said: id is unique in a DOM

Comment: this are checkboxes. No, it is not possibile to have more than one "primo" or "secondo" selected (but I have already solved this problem)

Comment: If it is not possible to have multiple choice you are using checkboxes to do the job of radio buttons. Radio Buttons have all the same name and only the checked one will be posted (as you do). Check Boxes have an array as name (like name="primi[]") and all the checked values will be posted inside this array. Can I suggest you to have a closer look at the differences between the two html tags?

Comment: I know that radio buttons are the best way for my problem, but I can't for other things

Answer (score 2):

It is because of your logic, in your for loop if the first checkbox is not checked you are showing the alert and is returning from the function without giving the for loop an opportunity to check the rest of elements.

```
var i, primi = document.getElementsByName('primi');
for (i = 0; i <= primi.length; i++) {
    if (primi[i].checked) {
        alert('yes');
        return true;
    }
}
alert('error');
return false;
```

Note: ID of an element must be unique, so unless you need an id remove the ID attribute, if you require them give unique ID for each element

Comment: thanks for your explanation. This works if I only want to check "primi". But if I want to check "secondi" how can I do?

Answer (score -1):

I am not able to completely understand your requirement. Please elaborate how primi and secondi are related. Also, according to your code you are return true and false , may I know why? According to me just remove return statements and try again ...You may use below code snippet:

```
    var i, primi = document.getElementsByName('primi');
    int flag =0;
    for (i = 0; i <= primi.length; i++){
    if (primi[i].checked){
        flag = 1;}
    }

    if (flag == 1){
        alert('yes');
    }else{
        alert('error');
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: "primi" is a thing and "secondi" is another. If you select "primi" you can't select "secondi". And if you select "secondi" you can't select "primi". I have to do this control...